# Handle redirects and implicit at assertions

Tags: geb

The website I want to test has a landing page which asks you to chose a language. You can skip this question by adding an extra parameter in the url. I want to test this behaviour with `Geb` and `Spock` as testing framework.

So I have the landing page with language selection:

```
class LanguageSelectionPage extends Page {

    static url = "http://localhost:8080/registration/"

    static at = { $("form#languageForm") }
}
```

The second page where it redirects to:

```
class InsertCardReaderPage extends Page {

    static at = { welcomeTitle1 }

    static content = {
        welcomeTitle1(wait: true, cache: false) { $("#eidWelcomeTitle1") }
        welcomeTitle2(wait: true, cache: false) { $("#eidWelcomeTitle2") }
    }
}
```

(I've removed some methods from the pasted code)

So this is my test:

```
given:
to LanguageSelectionPage, "09";

expect:
at InsertCardReaderPage;
```

The "09" is an extra parameter in the url, when this one is available you will be immediatly redirected by the server (http redirect, so the page does change) to the `InsertCardReaderPage`. Now, my problem is that the `to` statement performs an implicit assertion on the `at` closure. This one fails because you have been redirected away from the page already.

Is there a way to conditionally disable this implicit assertion in this case? Or any other proposal how to setup the pages? I'm pretty new to `Geb`and can't find any documentation that seems to help me in this case.

Comment: Would using a page without an at assertion do the trick?

Comment: I don't see that as a viable option. In 99% of my tests I want to make sure that you start from the `LanguageSelectionPage`. I like the feature that I don't always need to make an explicit assertion to check that.

Comment: Just a small note, cache: false is the default, you don't need to explicitly specify it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use via instead of to

```
given:
via LanguageSelectionPage, "09";

expect:
at InsertCardReaderPage;
```

[Geb Manual](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-checking)

Comment: Works like a charm! Must have missed that little paragraph when going through the documentation :(

Comment: I use it myself but completely forgot about it last night. Otherwise I would have answered sooner.